# Envio de Imagem do arquivo com FormData sem input file

Tags: javascript, imagem, apache-cordova, formdata

Estou trabalhando com o cordova, e ele não da suporte ao input file do html.
Gostaria de saber se á alguma forma de enviar uma imagem do arquivo pelo método formData do ajax.

Tentei enviar a imagem como Blob para o meu banco de dados, mas não consigo trazer a imagem original de volta.

Quando fiz teste com o inpt file, ele enviava a imagem sem problema com um parâmetro ContentType: "image/jpeg", pensei se haveria alguma forma de criar um parâmetro igual para mandar minha imagem com um formData.append('imagem', imagem);

Também há o file transfer, mas não consigo enviar a imagem, e queria algo mais simples e objetivo para enviar a imagem.

Obrigado

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// var formulario = document.getElementById('iformulario'); 
// var formData = new FormData(formulario);

// var blob = new Blob([imagem]);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('nnome', nome);
formData.append('nemail', email);
formData.append('nestado', estado);
formData.append('nsenha1', senha1);
formData.append('ntipo',tipo);
// formData.append('nimagem', blob, localStorage.getItem('imagemcadastro'));
// formData.append('nimagem', imagem);

$.ajax({
    type:'post',                                        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json',                                   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
    url: 'cadastro.php',    //Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    // headers:{'Content-Type':'image/jpeg','X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'},
    // ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    data: formData,

    contentType: false, 
    processData: false,

    success: function(dados){
        if (dados == 1){
            alert("Usuario Existente");
        }

        if (dados == 0){
            alert("Não foi possível cadastrar seu email");
        }

        if (dados == 2) {
            alert("Cadastro Realizado com Sucesso");
            window.location = "../index.html";      

        }
    }
    });
```

});

```
function editandoavatar() {

// var tranfere = localStorage.getItem('imagemcadastro');
var tranfere = document.getElementById('carregafoto').src;

var id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    // var tranfere = "IMG_0004.jpg";
    var server = "editaavatar.php";

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "nimagem";
    options.fileName = tranfere.substr(tranfere.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpg";
    options.httpMethod = 'POST';

    options.params ={ 
        nid: id 
    };

    console.log(tranfere);
    console.log(options);
    console.log(id);

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(tranfere, server, win, fail, options);

    function win(r) {
                console.log("Should not be called.");
            }

            function fail(error) {
                // error.code == FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
            }
```

Comment: Se possível poste o código que você tentou.

Comment: adicionei os codigos